# Load webpack hashed assets in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, assets

How do you guys load webpack hashed assets in a template engine? Like pug or EJS
I cant static load assets because the hash changes all the time

```
main.a05c1bb48101ada482bc.css     275 bytes  0  [emitted] [immutable]  main
main.a7cf4d76d563475b16d1.js      148 bytes  0  [emitted] [immutable]  main
runtime.f21d4814d853f9ad72d3.js  1.46 KiB    1  [emitted] [immutable]  runtime
```